# SQL Server Windows user authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, oledb

I have been given credentials to login to a SQL Server instance. I have tried several drivers/apps to login with no luck. For example using the Data Link / OLEDB way to test the connection. I get the following error:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Login failed for user 'corporate\username'

The username is a Windows account based on its format. My question is exactly how do these Windows usernames behave when logging in.

The OLEDB setup dialog says you can use "Use Window NT integrated security" but if you do then you cannot specify the username/password. So, does that mean you must be logged in a 'corporate\username' on your machine to ever login to SQL Server?

Comment: So, by not checking that you are not using AD account? And any username entered in the OLEDB setup that is a Windows account is destined to fail?

Comment: You need to run the application connecting to the SQL Server instance with the credentials provided to get *Integrated Security* to work. For example right-click SQL Management Studio and choose `Run as ...`. The same applies for Data Link, etc. See [SSPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/sspi) for the concept behind it.

Comment: With integrated security, you do not specify a userId and password. It is your windows account already and windows login is controlling your credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally getting past this problem. Here's the solution I found.

If you are running Windows and your machine in on the same Domain. I believe these comments about using "Run As.." and using "Integrated Security" should work. My machine was not on the corporate domain and so got "untrusted domain" errors. Also, this is a purely Windows solution which wasn't what I finally needed.

If you want to connect from Linux, Mac or Windows machines, then use the ***jTDS JDBC driver***.  You don't have to be in the domain. And thus you don't even need to be using Windows. You just specify the domain, username, password in the connection string.

Note that the standard Microsoft MSSQL JDBC driver will not authenticate against the domain. But this jTDS JDBC driver does.

Also if you need a client program Squirrel SQL works fine with the driver.